# swiftui - Post-Request to php-service not in POST-Array

Tags: xcode, rest, swiftui

i am new to swiftui and want to connect my app to an php-service.
the goal is to send username an password to the service via post, so that the username an password are in the PHP-POST-Array.
In my app the parts are in the payload so I can read it with

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

but I need the parts in

```
$_POST
```

Here is my code :

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://testservice.de/login.php")
else{
    print("Error")
    return
}
let parms: [String: Any] = [
    "benutzer":"test",
    "passwort":"test"
]
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
do{
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parms,options: .prettyPrinted)
}catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    return
}
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data else {
        return
    }
    let responseText = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "unknown encoding"
    print("The Response is : \(responseText)")

}.resume()
```

Comment: There is no SwiftUI in this code. This is just Swift.

Comment: Sending `passwort` in "clear" text is not a good idea. Do some basic search, in SO and the net, there must be hundreds of tutorials, explanations on this subject.

Comment: you are absolutely right, but that is not the question. the question is about getting the parameters in the PHP-POST-Array. i tried so many tutorials, but never get the parms in the POST-Array. If i make a request in Windows-Postman - the parms were in the POST-Array but not in swift.

Comment: as I understand with `Postman`, mac I guess, you can generate the equivalent swift code. That could help.

Comment: ok, i found the problem. i have to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded  - know the parms are in the PHP-POST-Array